# Subir y bajar archivos en el API de Google Drive

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-drive

Estoy intentando integrar en mi aplicación Google Drive pero no logro hacer funcionar el ejemplo que provee Google, obtengo el siguiente error:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

He identificado parte del problema y se da en `MediaHttpUploader.java` en:

```
private HttpResponse resumableUpload(GenericUrl initiationRequestUrl)
```

Más especifico en:

```
uploadUrl = new GenericUrl(initialResponse.getHeaders().getLocation());
```

Ya que al intentar leer el valor `initialResponse.getHeaders().getLocation()` retorna `null`.

He realizado pruebas sin ningún resultado positivo, si remuevo `mediaContent` de:

```
driveService.files().create(fmdt, mediaContent).setFields("id").setAlt("").execute();
```

Sube un archivo sin formato ya que el archivo va en `mediaContent`.

Alguien me pueda orientar como resolver este problema.

**Nota**: según documentación de Google Drive **Drive.driveApi** está obsoleta y no funciona más.

```java
public Task<String> newFile(String filepath) {
    return Tasks.call(executor, () -> {
        File fmdt = new File();
        fmdt.setName("contents.json");
        fmdt.setParents(Collections.singletonList("STRC"));
        java.io.File fp = new java.io.File(filepath);

        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.google-apps.unknown",fp);
        File mf = null;
        try {
             mf = driveService.files().create(fmdt, mediaContent).setFields("id").setAlt("").execute();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            for (int i=0;i<e.getStackTrace().length;i++) {
                Log.d("drive",e.getStackTrace()[i] );
            }
            Log.d("drive",e.getMessage() );
        }
        if (mf == null) {
            throw new IOException("null result");
        }
        return mf.getId();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error definido por `MalformedURLException` que nos indica que la url que tratas de usar esta mal construida.

Pero el principal error se provoca al tratar de obtener la información del Stack trace, no entiendo que tratas de realizar con su información, pero simplemente imprime su valor, no debes tratar de obtener su longitud para obtener su información, realiza este cambio.

```
  ...
  } catch (Exception e) {
        /*e.printStackTrace();
        for (int i=0;i<e.getStackTrace().length;i++) {
            Log.d("drive",e.getStackTrace()[i] );
        }*/
        Log.d("drive",e.getStackTrace() );
        Log.d("drive",e.getMessage() );
    }
   ...
```

En cuanto a lo que comentas que [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api) es obsoleta, no encontré esta información.

Si deseas un ejemplo, puedes revisar este:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Google-Drive

Comment: Gracias por responder, te explico un poco mas, en las lineas que marcas he impreso asi porque por algun motivo no me muestra correctamente el Stack Trace por lo que lo identifico manualmente, he reconstruido la clase Drive de forma local para poder evaluar el contenido y efectivamente al realizar la solicitud en  `"uploadUrl = new GenericUrl(initialResponse.getHeaders().getLocation());", ` se retorna un valor nulo y extraendo el location manualmente retorna "no protocol", en cuanto el link que proporcionaste es de Google DriveApi, la cual segun google ya esd=ta en des-uso